# C++/GLUT: Generating multiple asteroids/bullets

Tags: c++, object, glut

I am having trouble displaying and animation multiple asteroids for my GLUT asteroids game. I can generate 1 ok but when I try to add more the output is not right, createasteroid keeps getting called and just flashing up asteroids for milliseconds in different parts of the screen for some reason. I believe it may be because the objects are getting destroyed when the display function ends but I cant figure out a workaround  Here is my code so far:

asteroid.h

```
class asteroid
{
public:
asteroid(void); //constructer
~asteroid(void); //deconstructer

void createAsteroid();
float generateAsteroidLocation(float a, float b);
void animateAsteroid();
};
```

asteroid.cpp

```
#include "asteroid.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <GL/glut.h>

float asteroidX,asteroidY, V;
int numOfAsteroids=0;

asteroid::asteroid(void){

}

asteroid::~asteroid(void){

}

void asteroid::createAsteroid(){
// Translate to an area outside of the screen and then give a random velocity in     the direction of the player
asteroidX = generateAsteroidLocation(0, 30);
asteroidY = generateAsteroidLocation(0, 30);
V = generateAsteroidLocation(0.000030, 0.000050);

printf("Asteroid Y Location %f \n", asteroidY);
printf("Asteroid X Location %f \n", asteroidX);
printf("Asteroid Velocity %f \n", V);
printf("Asteroid Created! \n");

glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(asteroidX, asteroidY, 0.0);
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
glVertex2f(1.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(1.8, 0.0);
glVertex2f(1.4, -0.8);
glVertex2f(1.0, -1.7);
glVertex2f(-1.5, -1.0);
glVertex2f(-1.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(0.0, 1.4);
glVertex2f(1.0, 1.0);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();

}

float asteroid::generateAsteroidLocation(float a, float b){
float random = ((float) rand()) / (float) RAND_MAX;
float range = b - a; 
return (random*range) + a;
}

void asteroid::animateAsteroid(){
float dt = 3500;
float Dx = 25 - asteroidX;
float Dy = 25 - asteroidY;
float Cx = asteroidX + Dx / sqrt(Dx*Dx+Dy*Dy) * V * dt;
float Cy = asteroidY + Dy / sqrt(Dx*Dx+Dy*Dy) * V * dt;
asteroidX = Cx;
asteroidY = Cy;
}
```

main.cpp ( the functions causing problems )

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
#include "asteroid.h"
#include <GL/glut.h>

asteroid a1;
asteroid a2;

void display(void)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
// check to see if the player is ready, if not, show the splashscreen
if(ready == false){
    splashScreen();
    showText();
}
else{

    createSpaceship();
    // PROBLEM HERE
    a1.createAsteroid();
    a2.createAsteroid();

}
// Setup the scene
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, 50, 0, 50, 0, 50);
// call the needed functions
glutSwapBuffers();

}

void idle(void)
{
glutPostWindowRedisplay(glutGetWindow());
// PROBLEM HERE
a1.animateAsteroid();
a2.animateAsteroid();

}
```

Any help on this would be great. I'm stumped as to what approach to take. I can provide more information or a pastebin if needed.
Thanks! -Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply want to break your `createAsteroid` function in two, one which creates the `Asteroid`, setting its initial values, and another one that does the rendering.

You seem to have a `ready` function to know when the loading is done, it's around there that you should create and initialize your asteroids.  In display you should call a function that does only this part:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(asteroidX, asteroidY, 0.0);
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
glVertex2f(1.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(1.8, 0.0);
glVertex2f(1.4, -0.8);
glVertex2f(1.0, -1.7);
glVertex2f(-1.5, -1.0);
glVertex2f(-1.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(0.0, 1.4);
glVertex2f(1.0, 1.0);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

Also, you seem to recreate your player's spaceship at every `display` too, it should only be created in the initialization phase like the Asteroids!

**Edit:** If I'm not clear, when creating a game object you usually want at least 4 main methods: **Create/Init**, **Update** (where you would animate your object, do gameplay code like testing for bullet hits, etc...), **Render** and **Clean up / Destroy**. Sticking to that should really help you getting your game going!

Comment: ready is actually just a Boolean but I see what you mean. I will give it a go, thanks!

Comment: Just to add a follow up question. How do you recommend I create several asteroids ? I have an array of asteroid objects `asteroid Asteroid[5];` which I can initializing in an init method like you suggested. How should I go about creating/animating each one ?

Comment: @L337BEAN it would probably be simpler just to switch to a `std::vector`

Comment: I have no idea how to use vectors i'm afraid. For the purpose of this project id like to achieve the result using an array if possible.

Comment: @L337BEAN when you have to handle resizing, `std::vector` is _way_ easier than managing an `array` like you have. You can probably get away with only 2 methods: `push_back` to add a new Asteroid at the end of the list and `erase` to remove an asteroid that you destroyed. All the documentation is here :) http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: Ok, im having a look at it now. I create my vector `vector<asteroid> asterodVector;` Now do I loop through it and initialize each one ? Sorry if Im a pain, c++ is a not a strong skill of mine.

Comment: @L337BEAN I would go with vector<asteroid*> asteroidVector; Storing pointers is more convenient as when vectors grow, they need to move all the items they contain to another memory space, moving pointers is more efficient. What you would do is something like: `Asteroid* asteroid = new Asteroid(); asteroid->Initialize(); asteroidVector.push_back(asteroid);` and to remove you would do something like `Asteroid* toDelete = asteroidVector[index]; toDelete->Destroy(); asteroidVector.erase(toDelete); delete toDelete;` let me know if it's not clear :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20128/discussion-between-emartel-and-l337bean)